# SQL missing 0 values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have problem with one query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(scheduleevents.id) 
FROM workers
JOIN scheduleevents 
ON scheduleevents.worker_id = workers.id
```

This query result is:
Workers who have some events ( more than 0) in scheduleevents table but i want workers with 0 events too.
LEFT JOIN don`t work and IFNULL option so how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: What doesn't work with using left join in this case?

Comment: Just result is the same, only workers with events more than 0

Comment: Left join works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN, but you're missing a GROUP BY to get the result per worker;

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(scheduleevents.worker_id) 
FROM workers
LEFT JOIN scheduleevents 
  ON scheduleevents.worker_id = workers.id
GROUP BY workers.id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b5c5c/1).